# Android wear detect sound off switch

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-2.0

Is there any way to detect if the system sounds are muted via the sounds switch which can be pulled down from the top? Except with checking if all sound volumes are zero...

From my research it just sets all sound volumes to zero and "unmuting" the sounds restores the sounds volumes before mute. This is not very reliable way of doing this kind of stuff and if some app changes the system sound volumes it will "unmute" the watch and what is even funnier is that if an app sets the volume to zero, when the watch is muted = volume is zero, the unmute will leave at zero!

I need a reliable way of detecting this or the heuristic of checking if all sound volumes are zero is the best we have?

Comment: Try checking the [Detect the Speaker on Wearables](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/wearable-sounds.html). "Once you've detected the speaker, the process for playing sound on Android Wear is the same as for a handset or other device. For more information, see [Media Playback](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)."

Comment: @noogui There is no information about the watch's "sound" switch that can be swiped from the top of the screen. This switch is specific to Android Wear and is not present on phones.